# MUI pages order in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

How to change order of pages depending on some clauses? For example, there are 2 radiobuttons on custom page - 'repair programm' and 'uninstall programm'. When I select 'repair programm' next should show 5 pages and when I select another radiobutton should be 2 pages.
And is it possible use in uninstaller install pages and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM does not really make sense in a installer, other than that you can use all page types in both the installer and uninstaller.

To skip a page you must call `Abort` in the pre callback function for that page. You can also [jump directly to a specific page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Go_to_a_NSIS_page).

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Var pagemode
Function selectpagemode
MessageBox MB_YESNO "Mode A?" IDNO nope
    StrCpy $pagemode "A"
    Return
    nope:
    StrCpy $pagemode "B"
FunctionEnd

Function onlymodeA
${IfThen} $pagemode != "A" ${|} Abort ${|}
FunctionEnd
Function onlymodeB
${IfThen} $pagemode == "A" ${|} Abort ${|}
FunctionEnd

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE selectpagemode
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME 

;Mode A
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

;Mode B
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE onlymodeB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

Comment: It works for install pages, but when I use it for MUI_UNPAGE there're 3 warnings:
  install function "selectpagemode" not referenced - zeroing code (50-55) out

  install function "onlymodeA" not referenced - zeroing code (55-58) out

  install function "onlymodeB" not referenced - zeroing code (58-61) out

Comment: You have to prefix the function names with "un." for functions used by the uninstaller...